# Assigning variables to rows

Tags: php, mysql, variables

In my example below I am pulling six random rows and would like to assign one of the variables (a, b, c, d, e, f) to each generated row.

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM cub_posts WHERE active = 'Y' ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 6") or die(mysql_error());
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $demo_id = 'a, b, c, d, e, f';

    echo '<div class="span4 span-box">
    <div id="demo5'.$demo_id.'" class="ho-box demo5">'.$row['title'].'</div>
    </div>';
}
```

So the output would be:

```
<div class="span4 span-box">
<div id="demo5a" class="ho-box demo5">Title</div>
</div>
<div class="span4 span-box">
<div id="demo5b" class="ho-box demo5">Title</div>
</div>
<div class="span4 span-box">
<div id="demo5c" class="ho-box demo5">Title</div>
</div>
<div class="span4 span-box">
<div id="demo5d" class="ho-box demo5">Title</div>
</div>
<div class="span4 span-box">
<div id="demo5e" class="ho-box demo5">Title</div>
</div>
<div class="span4 span-box">
<div id="demo5f" class="ho-box demo5">Title</div>
</div>
```

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: That being said, what is even the question?

Comment: OK thanks, got it, switching to PDO

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add a counter.

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM cub_posts WHERE active = 'Y' ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 6") or die(mysql_error());

$demo_id = array('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f');  

$i=0;

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) { 

echo '<div class="span4 span-box">
<div id="demo5'.$demo_id[$i].'" class="ho-box demo5">'.$row['title'].'</div>
</div>';

 $i++;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Move demo outside of your loop

```
$demo_id = array('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f');  
$counter;
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) { 
    echo '<div class="span4 span-box">
    <div id="demo5'.$demo_id[$counter].'" class="ho-box demo5">'.$row['title'].'</div>
    </div>';
    $counter++;
}
```

But it will fail if you have more than 6 results. 
Demo id can have all the letters of the alphabet instead:

```
$demo_id = range("a","z");
```

Answer (score 1):

Notwithstanding the fact that you should not be using `mysql_` functions as njk has very nicely summarized, it's not difficult to come up with something that takes care of the first 26 rows:

```
$demo_id = 'a';
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) { 
 echo '<div class="span4 span-box">';
 echo '<div id="demo5'.$demo_id.'" class="ho-box demo5">'.$row['title'].'</div>';
 echo '</div>';
 ++$demo_id;
}
```

But you will need to think about what happens when there are more than 26.

Comment: It will become `aa` I believe.

Answer (score 0):

```
$char = 97
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo '<div class="span4 span-box">';
    echo '<div id="demo5'.chr($char).'" class="ho-box demo5">'.$row['title'].'</div>';
    echo '</div>';
    $char++;
}
```